# Is there a function that takes a list and returns a list of duplicate elements in that list?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

Is there a Haskell function that takes a list and returns a list of duplicates/redundant elements in that list?

I'm aware of the the `nub` and `nubBy` functions, but they *remove* the duplicates; I would like to keep the dupes and collects them in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a Haskell function that takes a list and returns a list of duplicates/redundant elements in that list?

You can write such a function yourself easily enough. Use a helper function that takes two list arguments, the first one of which being the list whose dupes are sought; walk along that list and accumulate the dupes in the second argument; finally, return the latter when the first argument is the empty list.

```
dupes l                                    = dupes' l []
  where
    dupes' []     ls                       = ls
    dupes' (x:xs) ls
        | not (x `elem` ls) && x `elem` xs = dupes' xs (x:ls)
        | otherwise                        = dupes' xs ls
```

Test:

```
λ> dupes [1,2,3,3,2,2,3,4]
[3,2]
```

Be aware that the asymptotic time complexity is as bad as that of `nub`, though: O(n^2). If you want better asymptotics, you'll need an `Ord` class constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with an `Ord` constraint you can use `group` from `Data.List`:

```
getDups :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
getDups = concatMap (drop 1) . group . sort
```

Comment: This may not work, if the duplicate elements aren't consecutive: `getDups [1,2,1]`

Comment: Thus the initial sorting.

Comment: But `nub` only assumes `Eq`, not `Ord`.

Comment: @Jubobs, but `Data.List.nub` is therefore the wrong function for almost every application.

Comment: @dfeuer I can't argue against that, but whether the OP's type is orderable is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this, which is extremely inefficient, is to use `nub` and `\\`:

```
import Data.List (nub, (\\))

getDups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
getDups xs = xs \\ nub xs
```

If you can live with an `Ord` constraint, everything gets much nicer:

```
import Data.Set (member, empty, insert)

getDups :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
getDups xs = foldr go (const []) xs empty
  where
    go x cont seen
      | member x seen = x : r seen
      | otherwise = r (insert x seen)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote these functions which seems to work well.

The first one return the list of duplicates element in a list with a basic equlity test (`==`)

```
duplicate :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
duplicate  []             =  []
duplicate  (x:xs)         
    | null pres = duplicate  abs
    | otherwise = x:pres++duplicate  abs
  where (pres,abs) = partition (x ==) xs
```

The second one make the same job by providing a equality test function (like `nubBy`)

```
duplicateBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
duplicateBy eq []             =  []
duplicateBy eq (x:xs)         
    | null pres = duplicateBy eq abs
    | otherwise = x:pres++duplicateBy eq abs
  where (pres,abs) = partition (eq x) xs
```

Comment: For efficiency reasons, you want to avoid using `++`, whenever possible; it's unnecessary, here.

Comment: @Jubobs, well, that is not *precisely* true, but I've not analyzed this particular use.

Comment: @dfeuer Avoiding `++` whenever possible is a good enough rule of thumb in my book.

Comment: @Jubobs, it's really perfectly good in some contexts because of list fusion. But you do have to think about when that applies (and check the Core if you're worried). Also, if you really do need this list glued to that list, you're almost certainly better off using `Prelude.++` than rolling your own.

Comment: @dfeuer I need to read more about *list fusion*, actually. Thanks for pointing it out.